# How to optimise the performance of this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-analysis

I am trying to run the code below. It works fine for small data size, but for larger data size, it is taking almost a day.

Anyone who can help to optimise the code or who can tell me the approach. Can we use apply lambda to solve the issue?

```
for index in df.index:

        for i in df.index:

            if ((df.loc[index,"cityId"]==df.loc[i,"cityId"]) & (df.loc[index,"landingPagePath"]==df.loc[i,"landingPagePath"]) & 
                (df.loc[index,"exitPagePath"]==df.loc[i,"exitPagePath"]) &
                (df.loc[index,"campaign"]==df.loc[i,"campaign"]) &
                (df.loc[index,"pagePath"]==df.loc[i,"previousPagePath"]) &
                ((df.loc[index,"dateHourMinute"]+timedelta(minutes=math.floor(df.loc[index,"timeOnPage"]/60))==df.loc[i,"dateHourMinute"]) |
                        (df.loc[index,"dateHourMinute"]==df.loc[i,"dateHourMinute"]) |
                        ((df.loc[index,"dateHourMinute"]+timedelta(minutes=math.floor(df.loc[index,"timeOnPage"]/60))+timedelta(minutes=1))==df.loc[i,"dateHourMinute"]))
                ):
                    if(df.loc[i,"sess"]==0):


                        df.loc[i,'sess']=df.loc[index,'sess']

                    elif(df.loc[index,"sess"]>df.loc[i,"sess"] ):

                        df.loc[index,'sess']=df.loc[i,'sess']

                    elif(df.loc[index,"sess"]==0):
                        df.loc[index,'sess']=df.loc[i,'sess'] 

                    elif(df.loc[index,"sess"]<df.loc[i,"sess"] ):
                        x=df.loc[i,"sess"]
                        for q in df.index:
                            if(df.loc[q,"sess"]==x):
                                df.loc[q,"sess"]=df.loc[index,'sess']






            else:
                if (df.loc[index,"sess"]==0):

                    df.loc[index,'sess'] = max(df["sess"])+1
```

Comment: Can you provide a (short!) example of your data and the output you're after?

Comment: This is quite expensive as you have a big O of `n^2` at least and then `n^3` on your last `elif` statement. What exactly are you trying to do before we go off and suggesting changes?

Comment: Usually if you are using loops in numpy or pandas you are doing it wrong. Try to use builtin features like vectorization, broadcasting, fancy indexing etc.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you're trying to do a database "join" manually, Pandas exposes this functionality as a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and using this would go a long way to solving your issue

I'm having trouble following all your branches, but you should be able to get most of the way where if you use a `merge` and then maybe do some post-processing / filtering to get a final answer